# Does wait() wait for the referenced object or the reference itself if called on a reference?

Tags: java, multithreading, wait, notify

In this case, will thread 1 actually be notified (while waiting for the reference instead of the object itself)?

```
static Object lock=new Object();
//Thread 1:
Object reference=lock;
reference.wait();

//Thread 2:
lock.notify();
```

Comment: `wait()` waits for the referenced object. In fact, it has no other option, because references are passed by value in Java.

Comment: In your example `reference` and `lock` point to the same object in memory

Comment: Try setting `lock` to null and you'll have your answer.

Comment: There is no such thing as waiting on a reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Waiting for the reference or the object pointed to by that reference is the same thing since a lock is obtained on an object. No matter how many references are there, if they point to the same object in memory wait(), notify(), notifyall() will work seamlessly. Check out the code below.

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue;

public class ProducerConsumer {

private Queue<Integer>      queue   = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(10);
private LinkedList<Integer> list    = new LinkedList<>();
int                         limit   = 10;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    final ProducerConsumer pc = new ProducerConsumer();
    final ProducerConsumer pcRef = pc;

    Thread producer = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        int i = 1;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                synchronized (pcRef) {
                    while (pc.limit == pc.list.size()) {
                        try {
                            pcRef.wait();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    pc.list.add(i);
                    System.out.println("Producer @work : " + pc.list.size());
                    pcRef.notify();
                }

            }
        }
    });

    Thread consumer = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                synchronized (pc) {
                    while (0 == pc.list.size()) {
                        try {
                            pc.wait();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    int val = pc.list.removeFirst();
                    System.out.println("Consumer @work : " + pc.list.size() + " : " + val);
                    pc.notify();
                }

            }
        }
    });

    producer.start();
    consumer.start();

    try {
        producer.join();
        consumer.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

}
```

Comment the below line and you will see that the consumer thread is waiting to be notified.

```
pc.list.add(i);
System.out.println("Producer @work : " + pc.list.size());
//pcRef.notify();
```

Answer (score 2):

The synchronized method evaluates the expression given to the synchronized block in order to figure out what lock to take. Then wait, notify, etc. need to be called on the same object, but whether the same variable is used is immaterial. The code evaluates the expression in order to get the object.

Now whether thread1 waits, is notified, and wakes up depends on the outcome of a race condition. If thread1 enters the wait method before thread2 calls notify, then thread2 will wait and then wake up once thread2 notifies. If thread2 calls notify before thread1 enters the wait method then thread1 waits forever.